# Azure AD: Web api call another web api. Grant Type Error

Tags: .net, angular, azure-active-directory

I have this situation below:

I have two web app in Angular, each one access one API(C# .net Core). Two Clientes and two backends.

I am using on behalf of.

```
 var objetoTest = new Dictionary<string, string>
   {
      { "grant_type", "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer" },
      { "client_id", "f33ac250-31d8-426c-ab2f-5dwer344410" },
      { "client_secret", "DrA4s6n.ArerettttaKXyztUzE-P-9N" },
      { "scope", "https://tesst.com/dfdffdff-2ade-4fe9-9bcb-ea95fd5893ae/user_impersonation" },
     { "requested_token_use", "on_behalf_of" }
   };

    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(objetoTest);

  var result1 = await pegarToken.PostAsync("https://login.microsoftonline.com/
e7deed85-bee5-45c36ff03523/oauth2/v2.0/token", content);


 var test3 = result1.StatusCode;
```

I am getting the error below:

"error_description": "AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'.

Could someone help me?

[image]

Please let me know if you need further information to help me.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called On-Behalf-Of flow. While it is a big topic to put into an answer, you should refer

- [Microsoft identity platform and OAuth 2.0 On-Behalf-Of flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow)
- [Scenario: A web API that calls web APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-api-call-api-overview)
- [on behalf of](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/on-behalf-of)
  .

[image: Flow diagram]

Comment: Hi, thanks
One more thing my web API B is called for another AplicationB. Is it possible to follow the same solution?

Comment: Check [Scenario: A web API that calls web APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-api-call-api-overview)

Comment: Hi I checked and I am getting the grant type error.

Comment: That's because the request body of the post request does not have it..https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow#first-case-access-token-request-with-a-shared-secret

Comment: No, it has a grant type.
You can see in the code above.
 { "grant_type", "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer" },